# How does Pix4D align overlaping images based on one GPS point

Tags: gps, mosaic

Images that can be imported into pix3d have only one GPS position labeled in center of the picuture. I am wondering how does this tool make mosaic (create one big picture with stiching together many overlaping images). Does it do with information gathered from other metadata such as yaw, pitch, roll?

Comment: What is pix3d? Images may also have direction tags in the EXIF data https://exiftool.org/TagNames/GPS.html. Those are probably utilized if they exist.

Comment: I mistyped - Pix4d is software which among other options allows you to make mosaic from multiple images.

Comment: Perhaps documentation helps https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015702911-FAQ-on-the-accurate-geolocation-pipeline